# django server (hosted on ec2 ubuntu) failing for multiple users

Tags: django, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, django-views, gnu-screen

I am trying to run django server on aws ec2 instance (ubuntu) using screen command.

```
screen -L python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

My script works in simple common way that it detects a POST request, processes and responds via HttpResponse.

My code looks somewhat like this in views.py.

```
def myResponse(arg):
   """
   processing here
   """
   #this function gets executed
   #code below does not get executed, it gets cut off when, new request comes
   HttpResponse("responseString")


def index(request):
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        """
        process here
        """
        #this function gets triggered, whenever post request is detected
        myResponse(arg) 
        HttpResponse("anotheresponseString")
```

When one user is interacting, and suddenly new user iteracts and new post request is detected, older flow get cut off. No error is thrown.

How do I handle multiple users ?

Comment: We need to see your code

Comment: done. added some pseudocode for views.py

Comment: Last time I check `runserver` is a single threaded web server and as such it does not support concurrent connections.

Comment: After you checked this last time, what was the alternative ?

Comment: It is explicitly stated in the documentation and elsewhere that runserver is for development only and **not** for production.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Gunicorn or Celery to run django server and handle your requests.

Gunicorn
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/

Celery
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html